# How to make a nested structure of from_tensor_slice to pass two arguments in Dataset.map with a tf.py_func wrapper

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to map a .h5 parser function with a `py_func` wrapper by using `Dataset.map()` to create my input pipeline. I want to pass two arguments: `filename` and `window_size` in the map function. The following code has a calling order: `Dataset.map` --> `_pyfn_wrapper` --> `parse_h5`

The disadvange is that with map() function the _pyfn_wrapper can only take one argument since the `from_tensor_slices` can't zip 2 types of data: string then int

```
def helper(window_size, batch_size, ncores=mp.cpu_count()):
    flist = []
    for dirpath, _, fnames in os.walk('./'):
        for fname in fnames:
           flist.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)))
    f_len = len(flist)

    # init list of files
    batch = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(flist)))  #fixme: how to zip one list of string and a list of int
    batch = batch.map_fn(_pyfn_wrapper, num_parallel_calls=ncores)  #fixme: how to map two args
    batch = batch.shuffle(batch_size).batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(ncores + 6)

    # construct iterator
    it = batch.make_initializable_iterator()
    iter_init_op = it.initializer

    # get next img and label
    X_it, y_it = it.get_next()
    inputs = {'img': X_it, 'label': y_it, 'iterator_init_op': iter_init_op}
    return inputs, f_len


def _pyfn_wrapper(filename):  #fixme: args
    # filename, window_size = args  #fixme: try to separate args
    window_size = 100
    return tf.py_func(parse_h5,  #wrapped pythonic function
                      [filename, window_size],
                      [tf.float32, tf.float32]  #[input, output] dtype
                      )


def parse_h5(name, window_size):
    with h5py.File(name.decode('utf-8'), 'r') as f:
        X = f['X'][:].reshape(window_size, window_size, 1)
        y = f['y'][:].reshape(window_size, window_size, 1)
        return X, y


# create tf.data.Dataset
helper, f_len = helper(100, 5, True)
# inject into model
with tf.name_scope("Conv1"):
    W = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[3, 3, 1, 1],
                         initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    b = tf.get_variable("b", shape=[1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    layer1 = tf.nn.conv2d(helper['img'], W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') + b
    logits = tf.nn.relu(layer1)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=helper['label'], predictions=logits))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(loss)

# session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(helper['iterator_init_op'])
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(f_len):
        sess.run([train_op])
```

One can run the following snippet first to create random data first

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def write_h5(x):
    with h5py.File('./{}.h5'.format(x), 'w') as f:
            print(mp.current_process())  # see process ID
            x = y = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.02)
            xx, _ = np.meshgrid(x, y)
            a = xx ** 2
            b = np.add(a, np.random.randn(100, 100))  #do something and add gaussian noise
            f.create_dataset('X', shape=(100, 100), dtype='float32', data=a)
            f.create_dataset('y', shape=(100, 100), dtype='float32', data=b)

# init data
p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
p.map(write_h5, range(100))
```

Comment: Your problem is not completely clear. `from_tensor_slices` can create dataset object from nested structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a nested structure of `Datasets` as the comment of @Sharky is one of the solution. One should **unzip** this nested args **at the last** `parse_h5` function instead of `_pyfn_wrapper` for avoiding error:

> TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is
>   enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.

One should also **decode** the argument because passing by the tf.py_func() args is converted to binary literal.

The code is modified:

```
def helper(...):
     ...
     flist.append((os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)), str(window_size)))
     ...
def _pyfn_wrapper(args):
    return tf.py_func(parse_h5,  #wrapped pythonic function
                      [args],
                      [tf.float32, tf.float32]  #output dtype
                      )

def parse_h5(args):
    name, window_size = args  #only unzip the args here
    window_size = int(window_size.decode('utf-8'))  #and decode for converting bin to int
    with h5py.File(name, 'r') as f:
        ...
```